# Filtering Forms feedback

Tags: google-sheets, google-forms

Does anyone know how to filter respondent feedback into different sheets on the spreadsheet?

For example, each sheet collects information for separate classes and I want the form information to be sent straight to each particular class when that class is picked.

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible. The Forms response sheet is the interface between completion of the form and access to the data in it. The conventional solution is to copy data from it to individual sheets as required.

Answer (score 1):

Google Forms does not include that feature there several ways to achieve the desired result like using formulas with [FILTER](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093197?hl=en) or [QUERY](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093343?hl=en) functions to get the responses to the corresponding sheet or by writing a script with [Google Apps Script](https://www.google.com/script/start).